# sp_change_users_login 'auto-fix', '<local_account>'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I execute the sp_change_users_login so that it will auto-fix all local sql accounts?

in other words I can run the command to view all local accounts:

```
select * from sys.database_principals
where type = 's';
```

I now want those list of users to be used in the sp_change_users_login procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a cursor to get the list of names, and then loop through the cursor results.  Within the loop you would do something like:
exec sp_change_users_login 'auto-fix', @nameVariable

You'd loop while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0.  It returns non-zero when you have FETCHed all the rows from the cursor.

Here's more detail:

```
declare @userVar varchar(30)
declare users cursor for select name from sys.database_principals where type = 's';

open users
fetch next from users into @userVar
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    exec sp_change_users_login 'auto_fix', @userVar
    fetch next from users into @userVar
end


close users
deallocate users
```

Comment: It looks like I need to exclude the 'guest', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA', and 'sys' users.   I'm getting the error 'guest'is a forbidden value for the login name parameter in this procedure.

Comment: Could be.  I didn't verify that sp_change_users_login actually accepted the names from the query you provided.  Just illustrating how you would repeatedly call a procedure based on a result set.

Comment: I added a not in predicate to exclude those id's.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note: `auto_fix` with Underscore `_` not `-`.